# Should I write each "team's", "teams" or "team" captain?

Tags: possessives

I'm writing about the captains of sport teams. Each team has one and only one captain. I'm confused on how to express this :

> We will communicate this information to ...

- each team captain
- each team's captain
- each teams captain
- each teams' captain

It's my understanding that *each* is followed by a singular as per https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/each, so I think I should use *captain* against *captains* (I could be wrong on this one too, though)

However, I'm confused with the "team" part. There are several teams, so should I pluralize this word here ? Also, maybe should I use the possessive `'s` ?

Which is the correct way to complete the sentence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be *each team’s captain*, because each implies you’re talking about each of several teams individually, so you can use *team’s* as the singular possessive.

Comment: But you can also write *all the teams' captains*

Comment: Aren't  "Captains of each team/ captains of all the teams..." better...?

Answer (score -1):

After two different investigations and the testing of approximately 200 cookie-drink-combinations Fisher announced the teams’ findings.

Comment: It would be better if you added some explanation of why you think this is correct.